# MEM_LIMIT in impala shell command

Tags: impala

I have some impala queries in a file and I want each time I am running the queries to set the mem_limit = 3gb but in the command not in the file inside

```
impala-shell -f /path/ (and add here the mem_limit)
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you pls try this ?
You can use --query_option=option=Val

```
impala-shell -f /path/  --query_option=mem_limit=300000000
```